# Google Classroom Share button not working suddenly

Tags: google-classroom

We integrated the Google Classroom Share button per these docs - https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/sharebutton - back in Apr. Today we noticed it was not working, and saw these errors in the JavaScript console. Googling for "homeroom_share_widget" turns up very little, though there is a page with a copy of another StackOverflow post where someone reported this on Aug 4th 2020 and it "resolved itself."

```
www.gstatic.com/classroom/sharewidget/widget_stable.html?usegapi=...com&pfname=&rpctoken=71244563:1 
Refused to apply style from
```

https://www.gstatic.com/_/hr/_/ss/k=homeroom.homeroom_share_widget.-6njcba4tmj9p.L.X.O/d=1/ct=zgms/rs=AK3ymSVKf9-q6qT49CxfhvwE4dkes0zTHw/m=share_widget

```
because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported 
stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

Comment: the request to widget_stable.html is successful, then it tries to reference css and js content, and that's what's failing.

Comment: A colleague found this issue in their issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/162785095

Answer (score 1):

Google identified the problem on their side and fixed it. See https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/162785095 for details.